# Getting float value from struct that is inside a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct Points that stores 4 floats. These structs are then put into a vector because I am storing points of a drawing (using OpenGL as well).

```
typedef struct {
    float x1, y1;                                                           
    float x2, y2;                                                           
} Points;

vector<Points> line;  
Points segment;
```

I now have a function where my two vectors are the arguments and I want to be able to access each structures points (x1, x2, y1, y2)

```
int CyrusBeckClip (vector<Points>& line, vector<Points>& polygon) {
    // How can I access each segment.x1 in the vector? 
    // (I reuse the segment instance for each line drawn)
    return 0;
}
```

How can I access each segment.x1 in the vectors?

I hope I am clear here and have provided enough info. I have tried outputting `&line.front();` but that did not seem to work.

Comment: line[i].x1 should do. You just need to access members of structs. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @therainmaker When I do this, Xcode gives me an error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: What is i?  The vector must have enough elements (i.e. i + 1 elements).

Comment: @AnonMail I used i[0] to get the first element. I even tried  line.front().x1 and I still get the same error.

Comment: But does your vector have a size > 0.  If not it will most likely crash.  Run it through a debugger or put a bunch of print statements to find out.

Comment: @AnonMail Ah okay, yes it starts empty because no points are drawn. But once I draw a point then the vector size becomes > 0. Now my problem is trying to find a way to call this function after the vector has a size > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// using an index
line[0].x1;

// using an iterator
std::vector<Points>::iterator = line.begin();
line_iter->x1; // access first element's x1
(*line_iter).x1 // access first element's x1

 // using front
 line.front().x1  // access first element's x1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Points& segment: line) {
    // here we can use segment.x1 and others
}

for (Points& segment: polygon) {
    // here we can use segment.x1 and others
}
```

This is called [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).